# Necesito un input range en una curva

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

Necesito encontrar la forma de hacer un input range (un slider) en una curva. La curva no se tiene que mover pero la bolita tiene que deslizarse a través de ella siguiendo su trayectoria (cómo muestra el dibujo).

[image: input range con una curva]

También tiene que funcionar para móviles (Android y iPhone).

Muchas gracias!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24994905/how-to-create-a-curved-slider

Comment: Gracias @Kiko_L pero no funciona muy bien en iPhone, no he tenido la oportunidad de probarlo en android pero...